# Moving wordpress site from localhost to live server using GoDaddy cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, wp-config, ftp

I'm using GoDaddy cPanel hosting to move my site from localhost. It's the first time I've done this and I've hit a dead end. I've followed the instructions from these [instructions](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/). I've used duplicator as a back-up whilst developing but I didn't use it for the FTP process.

I'm pretty sure there's a step in the process I'm missing but I can't spot it. I exported the database on localhost, created a new one in cPanel, imported across the localhost one. All the files are in the file manager portal but I'm not sure they're in the right place. The file trail is /home/cPanellogin/public_html/files - is this correct?

I've updated the wp-config file -

```
define('DB_NAME', 'new cPanel db name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'cPanel db user');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'cPanel db password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

The site link is [here](http://www.havoccreative.com/). I've never done this before so I'm pretty sure I'm missing some steps, any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: I see you have fixed this yourself

Comment: @BradHolmes Yes, thanks. I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the file path. I moved all of my localhost files from the subfolder into the main public_html folder. I moved a couple of existing files - home.html/404.shtml/layout.css into a sub folder and the site now works.